# Packages eccodes, cartopy, pyproj and gdal do not update via conda

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to update my conda environment, but some packages (for example cartopy, eccodes, pyproj, gdal) fail to update. These old versions now lead to changes in the result of my code, so I want to have them updated.

Current versions of cartopy, eccodes, pyproj and gdal in my installation are:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cartopy                   0.17.0          py37hd759880_1006    conda-forge
eccodes                   2.12.3               h4fa793d_1    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.6           py37h516909a_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      2.4.1           py37h5f563d9_10    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.4.1               hc4f5fd6_10    conda-forge
```

Updating all packages using
`conda update --all`
does not update these packages and provides the message that all packages are updated. Also `conda update cartopy` (and similar for others) does not update these packages.

Probably there is an issue with a dependency on another package, but I can't see which packages are now preventing this update.

Anyone that can help in getting my Python installation up-to-date using conda?

Comment: What versions are you specifically trying to get? Both`cartopy` and `pyproj` have a `proj` dependency. However, `cartopy=0.19` needs `proj>=7.2.0,<7.2.1` and `pyproj=3.0.1` needs `proj>=8.0.0<8.0.1`: they're effectively incompatible.

Comment: I'm trying to update `cartopy` to at least `cartopy>=0.18` and `eccodes` to `eccodes>=2.19.1`

Comment: Maybe you can dump a YAML (`conda env export --from-history > env.yaml`) and include it in the question or maybe post to Gist if it's very long. Otherwise, when you have real conflicts the recommendation is to create a new environment with only what you require for a project.

Comment: The complete environment is visible at https://gist.github.com/bbaa30/fa455da07928b77828342c8a100479c5. Probably making a new environment is the best option still